# Nested For loop only runs the outer loop in Batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a simple batch file, where for each file in file_path, the string after the 2nd hyphen in the file name is extracted and stored in Output.txt.
However, the script never runs the inside For loop and so essentially does nothing.
Both For loops work separately by themselves, but I can't get them to work together. I am running this in Windows Powershell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Break>Output.txt
FOR %%x IN (file_path\*) DO (
           FOR /F "TOKENS=3 DELIMS=-" %%i IN (%%x) DO (
                          ECHO %%i
                          %%i>>Output.txt
           )                            
)
```

Comment: you are running a batch file in powershell? I am a little lost here. anyway, what is the purpose, what do you expect the strip to do as you seem to want to capture a part of the filename?

Comment: The files I'm working with each have the same filename format (strings broken up by hyphens) and I just need to grab the string between the 2nd and 3rd hyphen for each file.

Comment: I'm lost too. Your code works fine for me ("as programmed", not neccessarily "as intended"). Please describe, what exactly you want to do.

Comment: then you need `... IN ("%%x") DO ...` to process the string of the filename instead of the files content.

Comment: (also `%%i>>output.txt` is questionable. I guess, you want `echo %%i>>output.txt`?)

Comment: Thank you so much @Stephan, your last two comments nailed it!

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell?